Sharing custom values between cells in tanstack columns
I have a quantity cell which contains an input. When a user inputs a value there i want that value accessbible to other cells. Right now im simply recieving an empty value in gross profit because its an optional type. Strange if tanstack doesn't offer any functionalies for this.
 {
    accessorKey: "quantity",
    header: "Quantity",
    cell: ({ cell, row }) => {
      const {} = cell.getContext();
      return (
        <div>
          <Input
            value={row.original.quantity}
            suffix="items"
            type="number"
            className="w-[120px]"
          />
        </div>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "gross profit",
    header: "Gross profit",
    accessorFn: (row) => {
      return row.quantity;
    },
  },

Gone through the docs but can't find any solutions here. State management doesnt work either because the accessorKey takes the value from the type.

The data values in TanStack's Row objects are stored under row.original --> Try row.original.quantity instead of row.quantity.
